# Generalizations of functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, geometry, functions

I'm trying to collection examples of mathematical entities that are generalizations of functions. The use of the word "generalization" here doesn't need to be strict, as in every function is an $X$ but not every $X$ is a function, but I'm looking for concepts inspired by the concept of a function.

Some examples I have so far:

$\bullet$ Equivalence classes of real-valued functions under almost-everywhere agreement, e.g. $L^p([a,b])$. The benefit is that you can work with these without worrying about particular values of your function, but at the cost of not being able to obtain any particular values of your function!

$\bullet$ [Correspondences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_%28mathematics%29), in the sense of algebraic geometry. These generalize functions in that they don't need to be single valued, but they are often (though not always) required to be at least finite-to-one. These are useful because they are a way of eliminating the asymmetry of a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ *from* one object *to* another. A correspondence is also a more geometric way of thinking about a function, and can be useful for moving (e.g. cohomological) information back and forth between two spaces when a bona fide morphism between the two is not present. (Side note: I read on MSE or MO the terminology that two spaces are *morphic* if there exists a morphism from one to the other, though I haven't encountered this term elsewhere.)

$\bullet$ [Riemann surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface). These could be considered an example of correspondences. They were originally used to study non-injective complex-valued functions such as $z\mapsto z^2$, whose inverses would necessarily be multivalued.

$\bullet$ Sections of a [sheaf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_%28mathematics%29). You can learn a lot about a space by functions on the space. Sheaves are the result of axiomatizing the collection of functions on space and forgetting the concrete baggage. Sheaves are extremely versatile, and the interpretation of sections as functions-to-what? can be very diverse. In the case of a structure sheaf on a scheme, we can interpret the sections as having actual values at points, but these values may lie in different rings at different points.

$\bullet$ [Line bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_bundle) A special case of a sheaf, whose sections can be considered functions locally but not necessarily globally. Then there are vector bundles, which are locally $n$-tuples of functions.

$\bullet$ [Differential forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form). These are another special case of sections of a sheaf, as they are sections of exterior powers of the cotangent bundle. In the specialer case of 1-forms, these are again almost functions. Given a fixed basepoint, a 1-form determines values at points, but values that depend on the path from the basepoint. So a 1-form could be considered a function on the universal covering space (up to a constant).

$\bullet$ [Distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29), or [generalized functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_functions). Yes, generalized functions are generalizations of functions.

I'm more interested in examples that are algebraic, geometric, or algebro-geometric, but I'd like to hear anything you come up with. Please share any new examples you know of, or any insight into the examples already listed!

Comment: How about the functions that arise in the area of math called [set valued analysis](http://www.eeci-institute.eu/pdf/M8-Textes/LectureSetValued.pdf)?

Comment: Distributions are functions.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, yes this example works. It is similar to multivalued functions.